# How to include maven libs in war when exporting from eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, dependencies, war, packaging

That title pretty much covers it. I have a maven project that obviously has a bunch of dependencies defined in it's POM file. But when I export my project to a war, none of those dependency libraries gets inserted into the war.

As far as I know all those dependencies should now be inside

> WEB_INF / lib

But.. nothing. I'm sure this is a very noob question, so please, a step-by-step guide on how to get this right would really be appreciated! Thanks :)

Comment: Why not using mvn package instead of the Eclipse export thing?

Answer (score 0):

You can export you eclipse project from UI as a `Web Archive`, so from *Eclipse*

- Right-click your project
- Choose **Export**
- Choose **WAR File**
- Pick up a **Destination** and click on **FInish**.

Check the generated war file under the specified destination and you will find all dependencies (Maven and Non-Maven ones) under *WEB-INF/lib*.

Comment: WEB-INF/lib basically not getting added in this way. I checked in my exported war file.